# querying between two datetimes in linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that takes 2 datetimes as parameters and I need to write a where clause to get the records that are in between. These are not just dates but dates with times (ie. 1/28/2012 9:45)

So far, I this:

```
where d.RecordDateTime > StartDate && d.RecordDateTime < EndDate
```

Should I be rewritting these as:

```
where d.RecordDateTime > StartDate.Date && d.RecordDateTime < EndDate.Date
```

or is it fine as is.

Thanks.

Comment: only you can answer this... Do you want StartDate and EndDate to be time-oriented or do you need to find anything between those date (00:00 till 23:59) ?

Comment: is RecordDateTime is defined as DateTime in DB ??

Comment: @Yahia: I want everything between 1/26/2012 9:45 and 1/27/2012 10:45 or 1/11/2012 4:22 and 1/19/2012 18:33. Both dates and times matter.

Comment: @Ravi: yes, it's defined as a datetime in the DB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current query definitley works... depending whether you want the result to include `StartDate` and/or `EndDate` it should be changed a little bit:

```
where d.RecordDateTime >= StartDate && d.RecordDateTime <= EndDate
```

IF you change the query as you proposed in your question then you would make it include all in the result independent of time - although it would miss rows with a time like 00:00:00 or even miss a whole day (the `EndDate`).

Answer (score 1):

you need to check for this link, as  it will tell the simplified way of filtering data in where clause [Where clause in datetime format](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Date_Range_WHERE_Clause_Simplification)

```
StartDtm < @ToTime  AND EndDtm >= @FromTime
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single date variablr and on model a RecordDateStart and a RecordDateEnd you can do:

```
 .Where(x => x.DtStart <= YourDate & x.DtEnd >= YoutDate)
```